# Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I tested my Fortran program today, the first time it worked well, and I hope to recheck and run again. Ummmmm, it said "Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it." but I did nothing, I just rerun again. Soooo, if anyone could tell me what's wrong with it?
Yeah,I have tried any methods I find on the internet,like add the sentence to the tasks.json.
"presentation": {
"reveal": "silent",
"clear": true
}

But, it didn't work.
Thank you for your kindness help

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Whit kind of terminal do you use? Which operating system? How exactly are you executing your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.